# ¿Como resuelvo problema al abrir Modal de Bootstrap en asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap, aplicación-web, modal

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ASP.NET y he creado un Modal el cual se abre con un botón, el problema es que cada vez que presiono el boton para abrir el Modal, este se abre a la vez que la pagina se tilda obligandome a presionar F5 para refrescar la pagina, le agradezco a quien me ayude a resolverlo.

**Este es mi código HTML del Modal:**

## Título

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Error al ingresar</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Usuario o contraseña incorrectos
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hola. No se cual es realmente tu problema, ya  que he reproducido tu código y a mi me funciona correctamente. Podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: Con que versión de bootstrap lo estas trabajando?